# How to resize Visual studio 2019 central panel?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

I have a problem with (at least) visual 2015 and visual 2019
(see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HUuR.jpg)

My *"central panel"* where everything is automatically docked now have a really small width preventing me from seeing file's content.

I tried to look in tools/option without luck.

Then, I tried to remove the folder "ComponentModelCache" in `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{version}\`

Originally i had only visual 2015 so i tried to install visual 2019 but unfortunately it seams to have automatically loaded the settings witch cause the issue.
I also tried to open the developer command prompt and use `/ResetUserData, /ResetSettings` and even `/ResetSkipPkgs` in despair.

On dropping a file on the central pannel visual 2019 it gives me an exception of type  `ObjectDisposedException` (which wasn't occurring in visual 2015) and say it might be caused by an extension but i have nothing fancy installed.

I can still use windows/float to get access to the files but having to do that every time i open a file is inconvenient

I also have a visual 2012 installed for an other project but the UI works fine and doesn't seemed affected by the issue.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the window layout using the "Reset Window Layout" on the "Window" menu?

Comment: I did, it does reset witch tabs are open and where they are but not their size (or at least not the one i'm concerned about).